# Xen 6.2 - how to free up space?

Tags: xenserver

I have an HA pool of 3 Xen 6.2 machines. On each the root volume is > 90% full. I've updated the logrotate scripts to keep `/var/log` clean but have found that lots of space is taken up by `/var/patch`. In this folder are all the files (by UUID) uploaded to update the OS.

I'm wondering about clearing these out and what will happen. According to [this](http://www.visions.se/category/virtualization/xenserver/) page one can remove all the patch files with a single command.

My question: has anyone tried this? Any other strategies for freeing available space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across [this](http://xenserver.org/component/easyblog/entry/xenserver-root-disk-maintenance.html) post on the xenserver site.

Essentially:

1. Clean up patches once they are applied
2. Watch for /var/log filling up
3. Watch for /tmp
4. Includes a handy script to notify you when disks are filling up